# How does one change the size (width + height) of the XML layout preview panels in the ADT plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

I'd also like a way to change the default, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: ADT Screenshot]

A & B allow you to set the width(A) and the height(B) of the preview panel. C allows you to change the theme involved (including disabling the top bar, title bar, etc).

*Not sure how to change the default yet.*